# Can we define a norm such that the space of all infinite sequences is a Hilbert space?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, normed-spaces

I have seen a proposition that there is no norm that can be defined on the vector space $\mathbb{K}^{\infty} = \{(x_1,x_2,...):x_1, x_2, ... \in \mathbb{K}\}$ where $\mathbb{K} = \mathbb{C}$ or $\mathbb{R}$.

I guess we need to somehow show that for any norm, there is some $u, v \in \mathbb{K}^{\infty}$ such that $u$ and $v$ don't satisfy the triangle inequality, but I can't come up with a proof.

I've also tried to use contradiction, and show that if a norm satisfies the parallelogram inequality it fails one of the norm properties, but I've also had no luck.

Thanks for any help/advice!

Edit: I was wrong, there is a norm that makes it an inner-product space. The reason it is not a Hilbert space is because it cannot be made complete. I am confused about how to show this now, though!

Comment: You can define many inner-product induced norms on $\mathbb{K}^\mathbb{N}$. Pick a Hamel basis $B$ for $\mathbb{K}^\mathbb{N}$ and define

$$\left\langle\sum_{b \in B}\alpha_B b, \sum_{b \in B}\beta_b b\right\rangle = \sum_{b \in B} \alpha_b\overline{\beta_b}$$

Are you instead claiming that $\mathbb{K}^\mathbb{N}$ equipped with any inner product cannot be a Hilbert space (i.e. complete)?

Comment: $\mathbb K^\mathbb N$ has a Hamel basis of cardinality $\mathbb c$, so as a vector space it is isomorphic to any other vector space with a Hamel basis of that cardinality, e.g. $\ell^2$.  Thus it certainly **can** be made into a Hilbert space with an appropriate inner product.  Perhaps the claim should be that there is no such norm for which the coordinate maps $(x_1, x_2, \ldots) \mapsto x_i$ are continuous?

Comment: Ah, that's probably right. Does that mean there is an inner-product induced norm on $\mathbb{K}^{\infty}$, but for any inner-product induced norm $\mathbb{K}^{\infty}$ is not complete? How would I show this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have made a few mistakes in the statement so I will make a guess on what you really want to prove. ( Any norm satisfies triangle inequality and there are norms and inner products on $K^{\mathbb N}$  as mechanodroid has pointed out). So I will show that no norm on $K^{\mathbb N}$ is compatible with product topology. Let $||.||$ be a norm on $K^{\mathbb N}$ which is makes the coordinate maps continuous. Consider the closed unit ball $B$ under this norm.  Since the coordinate maps are linear and continuous it follows the k-th coordinates of the points of $B$ are bounded for each $k$. By Tychonoff's Theorem this implies that $B$ is relatively compact. But that would make  $K^{\mathbb N}$ finite dimensional, which is a contradiction. Thus even incomplete norms do not exist on this space.

Comment: Thank you! I don't understand some of your answer though as I'm fairly new to functional analysis and don't know much topology. First, am I right in saying that || . || makes the coordinate map continuous, because the inner product is continuous with respect to the induced norm? Is there another way of showing this without using a topological argument?